# Select a record only if a newer record does not exist

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having a hard time getting my head around a query here that seems relatively simple.

Basically I have a table of Contracts for my users.  Each user has multiple contracts.  When a contract expires it is not flagged as such and if the user renews with us a new Active contract record is created with a new end date in the future and we go by that.

What I want to do is create a query that selects all users who have contracts that are expired, but have not renewed with us.

For simplicity sake here is a simple version of my contract table.

```
+------+----------+--------+
|UserID|ContractID|End Date|
+------+----------+--------+
|1     |1         |1/1/2014|
+------+----------+--------+
|2     |2         |1/1/2015|
+------+----------+--------+
|3     |3         |1/1/2014|
+------+----------+--------+
|1     |4         |1/1/2015|
+------+----------+--------+
```

So you can see user 1 has an active and inactive contract, user 2 has only active, and user 3 has only inactive.  I need my query to only find user 3 as he has not renewed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in a `Where` clause to see if the user does not have a contract that has an end date greater than right now.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM Contract c
WHERE EndDate < GetDate()
    AND NOT EXISTS
    (
         SELECT
             1
         FROM Contract ic
         WHERE ic.UserID = c.UserID
             AND ic.EndDate > GetDate()
    )
```

Comment: The only thing I'd advise here is that GetDate() will be evaluated for every row, which will slow things down considerably as well as cause side effects. It would be better to store the value of GetDate() in a variable and compare EndDate to the variable instead.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll - Strangely, no.  GETDATE() is a treated as a [run-time constant function](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/conor_cunningham_msft/archive/2010/04/23/conor-vs-runtime-constant-functions.aspx). It may still be clearer, and in the case of using multiple statements appropriate, to cache the current date/time in a variable.

Comment: All the testing I just did shows that `GETDATE()` is actually more efficient. It gives a more accurate estimate of rows returned. Very interesting. Keep in mind the difference is tiny.

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT UserId
FROM Contract
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING MAX(EndDate) < GETDATE()
```